# preg_replace syntax

Tags: php

I have an existing piece of code that successfully from what I can tell replace empty form values for a text field called your-subject.  I need to do the same thing for another field called Bcc.  I cannot seem to get my syntax correct when I try to add the name="Bcc" field.  Can someone show me the proper syntax? The page just simply fails to load so I'm guessing I missed a quote or escape character somewhere?

Works fine:

```
echo preg_replace('!<input type="text" name="your-subject" value=""!'
    ,'<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="MLS# '.$row['mlnum'].'"'
    ,do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="17" title="Contact Form"]' )
);
```

Broken:

```
echo preg_replace('!<input type="text" name="your-subject" value=""!'
    ,'<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="MLS# '.$row['mlnum']
        .'"''!<input type="text" name="bcc" value=""!'
    ,'<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="test@test.com"'
    ,do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="17" title="Contact Form"]' )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your lines!

```
echo preg_replace(
    '!<input type="text" name="your-subject" value=""!',
    '<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="MLS# ' . $row['mlnum'] . '"',
     do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="17" title="Contact Form"]' )
);

echo preg_replace(
    '!<input type="text" name="your-subject" value=""!',
    '<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="MLS# ' . $row['mlnum'] . '"''!<input type="text" name="bcc" value=""!',
    '<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="test@test.com"',
    do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="17" title="Contact Form"]' )
);
```

Now the problem becomes clearer on the second one: `'"''!<input...'` is an invalid string literal:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```